# How can we remove Noise from audio that comes out of Remote IO?

Tags: iphone, audiounit

I am  using Remote IO to capture voice real time and playback through headphone. When I test it the device(iPhone or iPad), I always hear a continuous noise in the background .

How can we remove these noise from the audio?
Can we use Voice Processing IO to cancel the noise and make the audio with out noises?

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this ? if so can you post some code. having a lot of trouble with audiounits at the minute

Comment: I did not get any solution for this.